# What are the relationships of the Gifts of the Holy Ghost to the beatitudes and virtues?

Tags: catholicism, pneumatology, thomas-aquinas, spiritual-gifts, pentecost

According to Catholic theology, what are the relationships of the seven Gifts of the Holy Ghost to the beatitudes and virtues?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From Garrigou-Lagrange, O.P.'s [*The Three Ages of the Spiritual Life*](https://isidore.co/calibre#panel=book_details&book_id=6076), part I, article IV, "[The Seven Gifts of the Holy Ghost](https://web.archive.org/web/20120131075405/http://www.christianperfection.info/tta10.php#Bk3)" (fn. 39), the relationship between the gifts of the Holy Ghost and the beatitudes, based on St. Thomas Aquinas's doctrine:

1. Gift of Wisdom → Peacemakers ([IIa IIae, q.45, a.6](https://isidore.co/aquinasBilingual/summa/SS/SS045.html#SSQ45A6THEP1)): "it gives peace and allows the soul possessing it to give it to others, at times even to the most troubled"
2. Gift of Understanding → Clean of Heart ([q.8, a.7](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/SS/SS008.html#SSQ8A7THEP1)): "those who possess this cleanness of heart begin here on earth, in a certain way, to see God in all that happens to us"
3. Gift of Knowledge → Mourners ([q.9, a.4](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/SS/SS009.html#SSQ9A4THEP1)): "shows us the gravity of sin" (which is the turning to creatures instead of God)
4. Gift of Counsel → The Merciful ([q.52, a.4](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/SS/SS052.html#SSQ52A4THEP1)): "inclines the soul to mercy"
5. Gift of Piety → The Meek ([q.121, a.2](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/SS/SS121.html#SSQ121A2THEP1)): "makes us see in men not rivals, but children of God and our brothers"
6. Gift of Fortitude → Those Hungering & Thirsting for Justice ([q.139, a.2](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/SS/SS139.html#SSQ139A2THEP1)): they "never become discouraged"
7. Gift of Fear → The Poor in Spirit ([q.19, a.12](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/SS/SS019.html#SSQ19A12THEP1)): "they possess the holy fear of the Lord, which is the beginning of wisdom"

The relationship of the gifts to the virtues:
[image: Gifts diagram]

See also Benedict Ashley, O.P.'s "[The Gifts of the Holy Spirit](https://web.archive.org/web/20120205104030/http://www.domcentral.org/study/ashley/gifts.htm)."

Comment: excellent answer!.